# How to programmatically show a UIView in a UIScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have UIViewA, UIViewB, UIViewC in a UIScrollView.
I want to see UIViewB first. (Note the order has to stay A, B, C)

How do I do that?

thx

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate. Please edit your question to explain, first of all, what you mean by "frame #3", and how your views are created and set up.

Comment: i have 10 UIViews and I want to view the 3rd one.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly without more information.  But as a brief overview, let's say you have 10 views in UIScrollView that have the same dimensions as the UIScrollView bounds, so that they're oriented vertically in a row in the scroll view.  The easiest way to show the 3rd view is to set the content offset of the scrollview to the origin of the 3rd view:

One of two ways to do this.  First is to just take the 'index' of the view and multiply it by the bounds height of the scrollview (this is useful if you have your views in an Array):

```
NSUInteger viewIndex = [someArray indexOfObject:viewToShow];
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, scrollView.bounds.size.height * viewIndex);
```

The other way would be to just set the offset to the actual frame origin of the view (this can be useful if the views aren't the same size as the scroll view bounds):

```
scrollView.contentOffset = viewToShow.frame.origin;
```

Both should work fine.